# Push Notification Amazon SNS - Mensagem cortada

Tags: c#, android, push-notification, sns

Olá,

Estou usando o Amazon SNS para fazer disparos de Push através do C#.

No dispositivo Android, a mensagem é cortada em uma linha, e ao clicar nela, a aplicação é redirecionada diretamente para o aplicativo. Porém há outros pushs, no mesmo dispositivo, com mais linhas, o que me leva a crer que não é uma limitação da mensagem em si.

Já no dispositivo Apple, a mensagem não está restrita a esse tamanho.

Alguém sabe se é possível setar a quantidade de linhas, ou alguma outra sugestão para que o usuário consiga ler a notificação completa?

Thks!

Comment: O que você já tem implementado de código?

Comment: Estou testando pelo painel da Amazon.O seguinte código gera pushes duplicados,mas um deles é expansível. O link (google) colocado no push também não funciona: `{ "collapse_key": "demo","default": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", "GCM":"{\"notification\":{\"body\":\"Check out these awesome deals! I said:Check out these awesome deals!\",\"title\":\"test\",\"url\":\"www.google.com.br\"}}" }`

Comment: Porém, se eu enviar a mensagem via data, só vai uma mensagem. Porém não sei como passar o link que preciso enviar, além de o texto ser cortado em apenas uma linha. 
`"data" : {
     "Nick" : "Mario",
     "body" : "great match!great ma great match!great match!great match!great match!great match!great match!tch! g reat match!great match!  ",
     "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
   }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As configurações do aplicativo não estavam preparadas para receber pushes no padrão "notification", por isso a mensagem não estava sendo exibida corretamente, além de ser duplicada.
O tratamento para exibir mais de uma linha precisou ser feito do lado do aplicativo.